# Laravel 4 PHP: 'Use' statement with both local files and package files

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to include a custom defined validation file that is local to my system and wish to use it with 'package' files from an application I downloaded online.  The purpose is so that I can have my own custom validators since I made modifications to this application.

I keep getting the error -> 'Class 'Models\Validators\Photo' not found'

**Controller:**

```
 use JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Controllers\AlbumsController; /* From Package */

 use JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Controllers\PhotosController; /* From Package */

 use JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Models\Album; /* From Package */

 use JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Models\Photo; /* From Package */

 use Models\Validators as Validators; /* Custom local file */

class EditPhotosController extends PhotosController {

    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }    

    public function update($albumId, $photoId)
     {
        $input = \Input::except('_method');

        $validation = new Validators\Photo($input); // Here's where error occurs

        /* Validation check and update code etc. */ 
     }  

   }

}
```

**Photo.php ->  File path:   Models\Validators\Photo.php**

```
namespace Models\Validators;

class Photo extends Validator {

public static $rules = array(
        'album_id' => 'required',
        'photo_name' => 'required',
        'photo_description' => 'max:255',
    );
}
```

Is this just a simple namespacing issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is that composer doesn't add file `Models/Validators/Photo.php` to the autoload index. Make sure you have provided correct path for your files in `composer.json`.

Comment: In my composer.json file, I actually have defined in my autoload index 'app/models' which is where 'Models/Validators/Photo.php' lives.  I tried using 'php artisan dump-autoload' earlier but that didn't do anything.  I'm a little reluctant to use 'composer dump-autoload' because I don't want it to 'undo' any changes I've made.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I created a new local directory called 'app/validators' and put the custom validation files in there.  Within my custom validation files, I had to add at the top of each file 'namespace app\validators;'.  After writing this command, I went into Putty and typed 'php artisan dump-autoload' and my validation now works.  Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Actually why it didn't work in `app/models` is because composer doesn't look for `PSR-0` matches in the directory. It only looks for direct files (which means not recursively) which contains a class with the same name as file. If you add a `PSR-0` or `PSR-4` object to composers autoload array and move `app/models` into it, previous locations would probably work. But `app/validator` folder makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to regenerate the autoload files.

Comment: I actually used 'php artisan dump-autoload' instead of 'composer dump-autoload' since it's been safer for me.  I actually found out it was both a namespacing and 'class autoload' issue.  Thanks for your suggesstion!